# Workflow to copy each time a list is updated/new item added in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow, lookup, sharepoint-designer

it's been a while since I have used sharepoint workflows

I have a list (lets call it A) - this has a lookup column (story) which looks at List C. This works fine.

I need list B to lookup the 'story' column from list A, however you cannot do a lookup on a lookup. To get round this, I want to create a workflow that copies the story column in list A to a new column (story copy) every time the the story column has a new entry or is changed/updated. I can then use a lookup from list C to lookup the story copy column in list A.

I hope this is clear, it is hard to word

If anyone could advise on the required steps and actions i'd appreciate it